# Filling large hole to screw/drill into again

Tags: walls, screws, drill, radiator, anchor

I have a radiator which was not on properly. I tries tightening the screws but the original plaster just gave way.

I filled it with 2 products (polycell and ronseal) which both claimed they could take a screw and be re-drilled. The radiators is on but is hanging off a little from the wall.

Is there  better product - mortar or similar that would set hard and take a screw?

Comment: Plaster walls are okay for screws holding a small picture or something like a clock.  For something heavy like a radiator, you should find where the wood studs are behind the plaster and screw into them.

Comment: Stud wall, or plastered brick, or what? Makes a heck of a difference.

Comment: What sort of radiator, is it one of those light-weight electric ones or a heavy iron thing?

Comment: Please respond with details requested by others. Otherwise, this post will be closed.